# ionViewWillEnter() not firing after a modal close

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I've got a component that shows a list of items fetched from a service, well from a remote API.
when you open the "add new item" modal and add a new item, and then OK button and closes this modal, no change in the list of items - the newly created item not seen on the list.
also checked - ionViewWillEnter() not firing after closing the modal and inside ionViewWillEnter() is the fetching from db:

```
this.feedingService.fetchFeedingListByBabyIdFromAPI(this.babiesService.getChosenBabyID())
       .subscribe((response) => {
       this.feedings = response;
     });
```

Comment: `ionViewWillEnter` of your parent page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ModalController` API [`onDidDismiss`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal-controller).

```
await modal.onDidDismiss();
//call feedingServiceSubscribe to reload list
```

Or you can even return data from the modal using onDidDismiss and set in your list.

```
const item = await modal.onDidDismiss();
this.feedings.push(item);
```

Showing a modal does not really change the navigation stack. So dismissing the modal does not fire lifecycle events of the parent.

Comment: thanx. Where would you advise to put await modal.onDidDismiss()?

Comment: just after you create modal